# debugging c using heap memory

Tags: c, linux, debugging, heap-memory

I am working with heap memory and I wrote an example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fd;

  //Alocate memory on the heap;
  char *UserInput = malloc(20);
  char *OutputFile = malloc(20);

  if(argc < 2){
    printf("Usage: %s <string to be written to /tmp/notes>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(0);
  }

  //Copy data into the heap memory
  strcpy(OutputFile, "/tmp/notes");
  strcpy(UserInput, argv[1]);

  //Print out some debug messages
  printf("___DEBUG___\n");
  printf("[*] UserInput @ %p: %s\n", UserInput, UserInput);
  printf("[*] OutputFile @ %p: %s\n", OutputFile, OutputFile);
  printf("[*] Distance between: %ld\n", UserInput - OutputFile);
  printf("_________________\n\n");

  //Writing the data out to the file
  printf("Writing to \"%s\" to the end of %s...\n", UserInput, OutputFile);
  fd = fopen(OutputFile, "a");
  if (fd == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error openning %s\n", OutputFile);
    exit(1);
  }

  fprintf(fd, "%s\n", UserInput);
  fclose(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

I execute is as : ./heap test
and the output is:

```
___DEBUG___
[*] UserInput @ 0x1a13010: test
[*] OutputFile @ 0x1a13030: /tmp/notes
[*] Distance between: -32
_________________
```

I think something wrong is happening with "Distance between" \\
max length of `argv[1]` in int type is "31" of integers\\
and max length of `argv[1]` in char type is "58" of characters\\
for example:

```
 ./heap 123...01 => 31 integers
 ./heap qqq..qqq => 58 characters
```

after that I face an open error...
why -32 is happening for distance between?

Comment: `UserInput` is completely superfluous btw.

Comment: Also, what do you expect the output to be? The two pointers do not point inside the same array, so whatever result you get doesn't make sense (and it makes your code invoke undefined behavior anyway).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is nonsense.

Comment: This is an exercise of heap overflow ...so the distance between must tell the distance actually...

Comment: how can define UserInput variable here?

Comment: Please describe much more in detail what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here.  The pointers are assigned by the malloc() function, which can and does assign fairly arbitrary values to the pointers.  A normal malloc() implementation will reserve a few bytes to mark the length of the allocated buffer, as well as taking advantage of existing buffer sizes on the free list.  So if you allocate two buffers, as you have done, there is nothing saying they have to be contiguous in heap space.  In fact, they will not be.

I don't know what you are trying to do here, but the 'distance between' two malloc() pointers isn't going to be the exact length of the buffers, ever.

Comment: thank you. but, how can I understand how many bytes I am allowed to give in argv[1] of my program? I think sth wrong is happening with"-32"

Comment: pay attention: this is a buffer overflow exercise using heap memory :) thank you in advanced

Comment: That's an ambiguous question.  If you want to limit how many characters you put into UserInput, use the strncpy() function. If you want to get all the characters, then use strlen(argv[1]) to find the length and malloc UserInput to the appropriate size (don't forget the null at the end).  Or you could just print argv[1] directly, and skip UserInput completely.

Comment: I want to pass the limitation of bytes number to overflow it.but the "distance between" should tell me how many bytes is normal and if I use more than it , the program must crash...but "-32" is strange for me..this program in another machine tell "24" for distance between. and if I use 25 bytes the program tells Open Error...

Comment: distance between is : distance between the address(0x1a13010) and address(0x1a13030)

Answer (score 0):

Malloc never assigns contiguous memory for subsequent requests.
It depends on the current condition of free memory.

As a good programming practice, please free both the malloc allocations before existing the programme i.e before return 0 statement.

```
free(OutputFile);
free(UserInput);
return 0;
```

Comment: @MortezaLSC - I have edited your code to free all malloc allocations before program exit.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work... thanks :)